# Corresponding noun for "side-effect-free"?

Tags: terminology, programming-languages

For functions or computations we have terms like:

- Deterministic – Determinism
- Pure – Purity

Now what is the correct corresponding noun for **side-effect-free**?

"Side-effect freeness"? "Side-effect freedom"? <strike>"Non-side-effective"?</strike>

Comment: Should this not be on [english.SE]? ;) In any case, could you give your usage context? I agree that using a proper noun of this kind does not feel right. (As a native German I sympathize; but we do have to force ourselves *not* to translate such monsters literally. They are almost always bad in German, too, if possible.)

Comment: Is side-effect-free different from pure?

Comment: @Raphael I also thought of asking the question there, but as I am asking about the *correct* corresponding noun in a programming context, I think that computer scientist may give me better answers.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I think that pure is *both* side-effect-free and deterministic, while side-effect-free may still be nondeterministic.

Comment: @Raphael There is actually no very specific context. I am currently thinking about how deterministic, side-effect-free and pure functions relate to each other. And to think about these concepts without having a name for each of them makes me uneasy. :D

Comment: Non-determinism is a computational effect, so now I wonder whether "side effect" and "computational effect" are the same for you. (Note: the terminology does not seem to be settled.)

Comment: you need to define 'side-effect-free', and even 'side-effect' ... The context needs to be given (along with some examples of side-effect-free and non-side-effect-free functions or actions, please)

Comment: When I say a function is side-effect-free, I mean that the function has no (visible) effect apart from the fact that it returns a value. Is this a valid definition? The computational effect would then be the return value.

Comment: Related: reentrant.

Comment: Thank you everybody for your answers. I didn't think this question would give rise to so many answers and discussions. I accepted David's answer now, but I like "nullipotence" almost as much. ;-) And while "side-effect freedom" may not be grammatically correct, I just don't like the longer "freedom from side-effects". I like Kaz's answer though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A good rule of thumb for grammatical questions is, if it's so complicated that you need to ask, it's better to just rephrase the sentence.  For example, "Side-effect-freedom of the function guarantees X" is more simply and elegantly written, "Because the function is side-effect free, X is guaranteed" or even, "The function has no side-effects, so X is guaranteed."

Having said that, keywords for articles are expected to be noun phrases so that would be a place to use "side-effect freedom".

(By the way, "non-side-effective" is an adjective.)

Comment: *(By the way, "non-side-effective" is an adjective.)* Good catch... And thanks for the answer. But unfortunately, I don't need the word for just a sentence.

Answer (score 9):

The word is *nullipotence*, the noun form of *nullipotent*. From the first definition on Wiktionary:

> (mathematics, computing) Describing **an action which has no side effect**. Queries are typically nullipotent: they return useful data, but do not change the data structure queried. Contrast with idempotent.

(emphasis mine)

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nullipotent

Comment: Wow, I have never heard of this term before. It does not seem to be commonly used (Google reports 16'300 results for "nullipotent" and 1'580 results for "nullipotence" and my browser spell checker knows neither of them). But I might just used it for the sake of it! Thanks.

Comment: I'm a domain expert and I don't think I've ever seen that term used. It's not a bad word, but it definitely needs to be defined before use.

Comment: This helped me to realize that there exists a difference between `nullpotent` and `nilpotent`.

Comment: @Val, yeah, I thought they meant the same thing until I studied abstract algebra. If I were feeling particularly cruel, I would explain it by saying that something nullpotent affects nothing, whereas something nilpotent effects nothing. :P

Answer (score 8):

Depending on the context, "absence of side-effects" may be a more readable term.

Answer (score 3):

I learned this concept as [referential transparency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_%28computer_science%29).

However, there is [some debate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865616/purity-vs-referential-transparency/4965613#4965613) as to whether or not this is actually a meaningful term, so if you're going to use it in a paper, you should define it first.

Comment: Referential transparency is not the same thing as absence of side effects. You can have a purely functional language in which macros bring about unwanted name capture left and right, thereby destroying referential transparency.

Comment: @Kaz Speaking of referential, do you have any references for that macro story?

Comment: @rolve I could be taking a too parochial view. For a contrasting one, see the Tunes project's definition of referential transparency which does have connection to freedom from side effects: http://tunes.org/wiki/referential_20transparency_20and_20state.html

Comment: @rolve I was thinking of referential transparency in the context of evaluation: code transformations can relocate expressions, yet the references in those expressions work properly no matter what. E.g. hygienic macros systems are said to be referentially transparent. There is nothing "accidentally opaque" between a reference and what it refers to, like a symbol of the same name inserted by the compiler in some invisible code.

Comment: @Kaz: As I mentioned in my answer, there are several conflicting definitions of 'referential transparency'

Answer (score 2):

Side-effect freedom, is what I would use.

Comment: Unfortunately, this has an interpretation that side effects have freedom, not that the situation is free from side effects; that is unambiguously expressed by "freedom from side effects".

Comment: Certainly. Even though that is true, I've seen it used in practice.

Answer (score 2):

If running the function multiple times has the same net effect on the system as running it once, the function is *idempotent* and has *idempotency*.  Don't know if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, that's another concept I will have to think about. Maybe one could say that idempotent is weaker form of side-effect-free. But it is not exactly what I was looking for. (And in any case it's not a noun.;-))

Comment: Good point - the noun form is idempotency.

Comment: exemple of idempotent function: `chmod` : you can re-run it several times, it won't do more than the first time (unless files changed in between...). There are many others. It is not exactly "side effect free" however as it does change things and could prevent other programs to do something too, once the permission changes.

Comment: The term is probably the most important in web programming - if you're modifying a database (adding new users, for instance) and you're dealing with the unreliability of a network, you need to make sure that duplicated messages received by the server don't cause unexpected issues.

Comment: Idempotent functions are definitely not side-effect free. N invocations of an idempotent function has the same overall side effect as 1 invocation. A function with no effect is a special case of idempotency.

Comment: Idempotent achieves the fixed point in one step. It does not have effect (i.e. is identity), once fixed point is achieved but it still may have side effects. Therefore, it is incorrect to say that sought function is somehow related with no-effect or idempotent functions.

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it with "side effect freedom". The problem is that this possibly means that the side effects are free (as in "freedom of side effects"). To be clear, you need "freedom from side effects".  And note how "free of" does not pair with "freedom of"; both "free of something" and "free from something" go to "freedom from something".

In general, you will find that compound noun phrases whose head is "freedom" are instinctively eschewed by native speakers of English, even though they are grammatical. For instance "freedom of speech" and "freedom from oppression" are not called "speech freedom" and "oppression freedom". The meaning could be worked out from context ("speech freedom" probably isn't "freedom from speech", and "oppression freedom" isn't "freedom to oppress") but the forms are simply not *euphonic*. Even if that is merely from disuse, it is the way it is.

Academic papers in CS are also written for a world audience which includes non-native English speakers. If you're able, then write like a native English speaker.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations, they seem reasonable to me. Would it make any difference if I spelled the word with dashes, as I did in the original post: "side-effect-freedom"? Or would that be just wrong?

Comment: The hyphens do not change the meaning. About hyphens, see [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/hyphen). The section on Compound Nouns applies.

Comment: Thank you so much for the link. I have never completely understood when to use hyphens in English.

Comment: "Side-effect freedom" is fine and widely used. There is no practical ambiguity because, of the two possible parsings, "freedom from side-effects" is a perfectly sensible concept that is often discussed, while "freedom of side-effects" is nonsense that nobody ever talks about. If a phrase has an obvious meaning, people won't go looking for other meanings: they'll just get on with reading the rest of the sentence.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thanks for the comment, I was thinking the same thing. It's still nice to understand that there is a theoretical ambiguity though.

Comment: "Side-effect freedom" is the standard, idiomatic phrase. There is only one thing it could reasonably mean; *ergo*, that is what it means. Grammar exists to serve us, not to enslave us.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want "[orthogonality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality#Computer_science)". It seems to fit your definition exactly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I think the word orthogonal is only used for concepts and not for computations or functions. It is, however, true that two side-effect-free functions could be seen as orthogonal, since they do not interfere with each other.

Comment: My understanding is that "orthogonality" was also used for functions (I think pure functions were called "orthogonal" sometimes). But I might be wrong, since "orthogonal" feels like it needs a second thing, i.e. something orthogonal to something else, so indeed it can't be that general after all...

Comment: But why do you search for a separate term for functions without side-effects? "Pure function" means exactly that: both deterministic and with no side-effects (says Wikipedia).

Comment: That's exactly the point: I want to reason about functions that are side-effect-free but not necessarily deterministic. Pure is already "too much".

Comment: I understand now. It would be an interesting exercise to search for non-deterministic side-effect-free functions. I can't think of any, except an atom, modeled with QM :) May I recommend thesaurus.com? Maybe there's an antonym of a noun related to side-effect out there. Also, maybe the word you need is a word that must be added to English from another language. I'll leave you alone now :)

Comment: Don't search too far. A `time()` function is non-deterministic and side-effect-free. Depending on the definition of "deterministic", even a getter function for shared mutable state could be said to be non-deterministic (and yet side-effect-free).